# how to use time() to count how many seconds you logged in

Tags: php, session, authentication, time

I'm creating a script and let's say I have a user/pass to enter and once it's entered another page will be redirected and in that page will show a line sayingi you have been staying here for xxx seconds.

I'm using $_SESSION at the moment but I'm not sure how to set up so time() will start counting after logged in.

this is my index.php script

```
if((isset($_GET["user"])) || (isset($_GET["pass"])))
{
    if(($_GET["user"] == "a") && ($_GET["pass"] == "a"))
    {
        session_start();
    $_SESSION["auth"] = 1;
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_GET["user"];
    $_SESSION["loginTime"] = time();
    $_SESSION["timeLogged"] = time() - $_SESSION["loginTime"];


    header("Location: 1.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Incorrect login data";
}
}
```

this is my 1.php script

```
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION["username"])))
{
    header("location: index.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION["username"] . "<br/>";
    echo "You have been logged in for " . $_SESSION["timeLogged"] . " seconds.";
}
```

Comment: Just pass the time in the URL or, if it's a POST, in the posted data.

Comment: You ahve to save the start time inside the session right after successful login. THen later take the current time again for each page requested and compute the difference against the saved starting time. You can also do that with ajax to get a "counting clock" on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$_SESSION` (as you mentioned)

Page 1 - store the current time (or any time for that matter) in a session (cookie)

```
$_SESSION['startTime'] = time();
```

Page 2 - subtract the current time (meaning the time page 2 is visited) by the time we passed in the cookie (created on Page 1)

```
if (is_int($_SESSION['startTime'])){ // if the cookie exists:
    $difference = time() - $_SESSION['startTime'];
} else { // if the cookie does not exist:
    echo "You have been here some time in the future";
}
```

Anyway... something like that might work

---

**EDIT** - with the code you provided:

Move `$_SESSION["timeLogged"] = time() - $_SESSION["loginTime"];` to your 1.php script. You need to calculate the difference *once you get to the second page* :)

what you had:

```
$_SESSION["loginTime"] = time();
$_SESSION["timeLogged"] = time() - $_SESSION["loginTime"];
```

That last line is = current time - (variable that also = current time) = 0

Comment: weird....I did something like that even though exactly but the seconds goes to 0....I'm editing my post and put the script I have

Comment: @user2128414, ya it's a good idea to put specific code, it makes helping you easier!

Comment: current, meaning, whenever your server is executing that php script (so when the page loads, i guess). Remember, PHP is server side, so once the page loads that is - PHP's job is over and that's the time stored when you use `time()`.

Comment: ah so right when it's directed to 1.php the timeLogged then means (current time) - (time logged in index.php) is that how it means?

Comment: oh ok hehe because then I thought I was asking super stupid question when I ask what current means...I deleted that comment >.<" because right after looking at the script then I thought the current time is created after the pass/user is correct because that's when the session is created and not when the page loads.  guess I am wrong oops :P